# What is causing invalid spatial reference error using ogr2ogr converting PostGIS to FileGDB in a Feature Dataset?

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, postgis-2.0, ogr2ogr, file-geodatabase

I am trying to use ogr2ogr to convert a layer from PostGIS to a FileGDB.  I want the layer to be created inside a Feature Dataset.

The spatial reference of the source layer is EPSG:3500.  The spatial reference of the Feature Dataset within the FileGDB is as follows, copied from the properties page:

```
NAD_1983_StatePlane_California_VI_FIPS_0406_Feet
WKID: 2230 Authority: EPSG

Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
False_Easting: 6561666.666666666
False_Northing: 1640416.666666667
Central_Meridian: -116.25
Standard_Parallel_1: 32.78333333333333
Standard_Parallel_2: 33.88333333333333
Latitude_Of_Origin: 32.16666666666666
Linear Unit: Foot_US (0.3048006096012192)

Geographic Coordinate System: GCS_North_American_1983
Angular Unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433)
Prime Meridian: Greenwich (0.0)
Datum: D_North_American_1983
  Spheroid: GRS_1980
    Semimajor Axis: 6378137.0
    Semiminor Axis: 6356752.314140356
    Inverse Flattening: 298.257222101
```

My assumption is that the WKID: 2230 with Authority: EPSG, means that this should be spatial reference EPSG:2230

I think the tricky part here is that the spatial reference is already determined with the Feature Dataset.  I've seen errors rise before when trying to designate a spatial reference where the output is a Feature Dataset.

Given the above, I thought the best step would be to simply try to convert to `EPSG:2230` without specifying the output spatial reference.  This resulted in an error.

Here is a sample command string and result:

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -of "FileGDB" c:\fgdbData.gdb PG:"host=server port=5432 dbname=ib_data active_schema=ibcommunitydev user=gis_admin password=xxxx" cdpo_zoning -t_srs "EPSG:2230" -lco FEATURE_DATASET=fdCommunityDev

ERROR 1: Error: Failed at creating table for \fdCommunityDev\cdpo_zoning (Invalid spatial reference.)
```

I tried a number of different combinations , including specifying the source spatial reference as `EPSG:2230` and letting it do a straight transformation, but nothing working.  They all returned the same invalid spatial reference error.

I tried using the same source layer and exporting to the File GDB outside of the Feature Dataset using the following command string, and it worked fine.

---

This string has to contain the variable `-nlt MULTIPOLYGON`, otherwise the table is imported as a non-spatial layer.

```
ogr2ogr -overwrite -f "FileGDB" c:\fgdbData.gdb PG:"host=server port=5432 dbname=ib_data active_schema=ibcommunitydev user=gis_admin password=xxxx" cdpo_zoning -t_srs "EPSG:2230" -nlt MULTIPOLYGON
```

The fact that the transformation to the spatial reference worked, leads me to believe it is an issue with the spatial reference of the Feature Dataset.

Comment: Have you tried EPSG:102646?  http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/?search=NAD_1983_StatePlane_California_VI_FIPS_0406_Feet&srtext=Search

Comment: @ew_gis - Yes, I tried that as well, and it didn't work.

Comment: Based on prior experiences, I strongly suspect the problem is in the literal name string. I note ArcGIS calls 2230 "NAD_1983_StatePlane_California_VI_FIPS_0406_Feet" per above, but EPSG calls it "[NAD83 / California zone 6 (ftUS)]"(http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2230/html/). Arc has given me trouble in the past where I was using the "same" projection, but in one case it was named with a dash and in the other that same character was an underscore - Arc said hey, these aren't the same thing ERROR. You might check this by looking at the properties of your import that worked outside the FD.

Comment: @ChrisW - What is odd though, is that if I create the layer outside the feature dataset and do the t_srs transformation to 2230, it is able to do it with no problem.  If you look in properties, it assigns the same spatial reference as the feature dataset is using.  I am wondering though, if some parameter is slightly different in the feature dataset that is causing it to fail.

Comment: Maybe vertical coordinate system issue not just horizontal? Can you move/copy the feature class that was successfully written outside the FD into it?